# Jquery scrollTop(), or offset(), or?

Tags: jquery

I have a div with a scrollbar. I have a bunch of spans and I would like to use scrollTop() or offset() to get my span to the top. I can get scrollTop( pixels ) to work, but I'm wondering if you can use an ID instead, or am I using the wrong function.

```
<div id="textOne">
  <span id="s1">I have a paragraph that is full of spans.</span> <span id="s2">I need to      be able to put each span to the top on command.</span> <span id="s3">I don't want them to automatically line up on the left, only on the top</span> <span id="s4">And I need all of the text to be accessable with the scrollbar</span>  <span id="s5">For this demo, I'll make a button to get to s3, but I need to do this in the background, so keep that in mind   please.</span>
</div>

<input type="submit" id="submit" value="SPAN 3">
```

---

```
$(function() {
    $('#submit').click(function() {
        $('#textOne').scrollTop($('#s3'));
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bdenzer/Yu5Jz/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add this to your event handler:

```
window.location.href = "#s3";
```

for example:

```
$(document).on('keyup', function(){
   window.location.href = "#s3";
});
```

Comment: No, I need to keep the paragraph as-is, I tried using scrollTop(50) and there is just too much variation in my text. I would just like to be able to scroll directly to a '#', like you can with <a href="#s3" -- but I can't do that, I need to do it in JavaScript or jQuery

Comment: Oh that should be simple enough:  
`<a href="#s3">Go!</a>`

Comment: I am not going to have a button, I am actually using a keyup() event to trigger it, but that would make the jsfiddle more complicated than needed.

Comment: Thank you, I tried to vote up your answer but I can't (no reputation) if there is anything I can do, let me know

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$(function() {
    $('#submit').click(function() {
        $('#textOne').animate({scrollTop: $('#s3').offset().top}, 500);

    });

});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Yu5Jz/2/